# Getting the uploaded file information using jquery-ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm using jquery-ajax to check whether the file already exist in my server.

I have this code:

```
Upload an Event Photo <br>
<input type='file' name='imageSrc' id='imageSrc' /><br>
<a href='#' class='uploadPhoto'>Upload Image</a><br>
<div class='uploadMessage'></div>
<span>Maximum size: 1MB (jpg,png,gif)</span>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.uploadPhoto').click(function(){
        // alert(1);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?option=com_eventsandrsvp",
            data: "task=uploadEventPhoto&format=raw",
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery(".uploadMessage").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I want to get the information that was there in the `<input type='file' name='imageSrc' id='imageSrc' />`

I know that that is a file type so there are information such as:
name,type,size, and tmp_name.

How would I do that using ajax?
I am trying to use a GET method but it doesn't work. maybe because it only works on `<input type='text' />`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files using just `jQuery.ajax()`, to upload files via ajax, you can resort to:

- Flash
- Iframe trick

Above methods have their own drawbacks though.

Fortunately, there exists nice script **[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)** you can use to upload files via ajax easily.